# upgrading ASP.NET website for IE8/Firefox

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I need to upgrade a ASP.NET website for IE8. it works fine in IE6, but not in IE8. I don't want to run it in any backward compatibility mode. I would like to make any code changes that are required to make it fully compliant with IE8/Firefox. what is the best and/or easiest way to do that? is it just a case of going through each of the things that are broken and fixing them one by one or is there a more efficient way to fix these issues (some kind of utility??). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no tool or utility to fix cross browser compatibility issues. You can make use of firebug(firefox) and IE developer toolbar to identify the points where the website is breaking.

But the good part is that you are upgrading from IE6. I dont think there will be major hiccups or problems making the website compatible with IE8 since its much better in rendering HTML as compared to IE6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have expression web, you could use SuperPreview: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx

THis is a great tool that allows you to compare you site in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you do have to go through each browser incompatibility bug and fix it for that browser.**  A bug can be fixed in 3 ways (listed in my order of preference):

1. Start with a very compliant browser, then look at the page in other browsers (I focus on Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE6-7-8-9)
2. Use different CSS technique, that ends up rendering the same in all browsers
3. Use [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html) to bring in another CSS for that browser leveraging the CSS "Cascade"
4. Use [CSS Hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks) as a last resort (usually only for Firefox or something)

But *"go through each browser"* can be the tricky part!  There are some tools to help.

@Brian mentioned SuperPreview for Expression Web (+1), but there's also a [free version of SuperPreview for Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en) for those who don't have Expression Web.

You can compare different versions of IE on the same machine (hard before this product).  Microsoft claims this sub-set of the Expression Web product will always be free (since they feel bad about IE6!).

IE6-7-8-9 tool is good enough for me, because I tend to focus on all versions of IE, but only the latest versions of Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

But if you must test against multiple versions of other browsers:

- Expression Web SuperPreview
- [How to Use Multiple Browsers on a Single Machine](http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/multiplebrowsers.shtml)
- [10 Helpful Resources for Cross Browser Testing](http://designm.ag/resources/cross-browser-testing/)

(Although Litmus seems to have dropped general web page support, and instead focuses on email client compatibility and campaign analytics.)